# Drupal print module - ignore code for print

Tags: php, drupal, printing, print-module

I'd like a way to ignore part of the code for printing. Should be visible in the module but in PDF output should not be seen. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you use dompdf, you should simply add css rules for "print" media type

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html